# QueueUserWorkItem weird behavior

Tags: c#, queueuserworkitem

I'm using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()` to start some background tasks.

The `ThreadPool` concurrency behavior is weird. My CPU has 4 logical cores. I expect that there are only 4 running threads. However, the sample code shows different behavior.

- in time 1/2/3, Why does mores threads are triggered?

here is sample code:

```
class Program
{
    static DateTime s_startTime = new DateTime();
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Queue the task.
        s_startTime = DateTime.Now;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ThreadProc, i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Main thread does some work, then sleeps.");
        Thread.Sleep(100 * 1000);

        Console.WriteLine("Main thread exits.");
    }

    // This thread procedure performs the task.
    static void ThreadProc(Object i)
    {
        DateTime thread_starttime = DateTime.Now;
        int a = Convert.ToInt32(i);
        double ss = (thread_starttime - s_startTime).TotalSeconds;
        Console.WriteLine("time:" + ss + ", start " + a);
        Thread.Sleep(10 * 1000);
        DateTime e = DateTime.Now;
        double ee = (e - s_startTime).TotalSeconds;
        Console.WriteLine("time:" + ee + ", end " + a);
    }
}
```

output

```
Main thread does some work, then sleeps.
time:0.0040027, start 0
time:0.0360007, start 3
time:0.0360007, start 1
time:0.0360007, start 2
time:1.0178537, start 4
time:2.0191713, start 5
time:3.019311, start 6
time:4.0194503, start 7
time:5.0195775, start 8
time:6.0195875, start 9
time:7.0219127, start 10
time:8.0214611, start 11
time:9.0181507, start 12
time:10.020686, end 0
time:10.020686, start 13
time:10.020686, start 14
time:10.038517, end 1
time:10.038517, start 15
time:10.038517, end 3
time:10.0403473, start 16
time:10.038517, end 2
time:10.0413736, start 17
time:11.0233302, end 4
time:11.0243333, start 18
time:11.0243333, start 19
```

Comment: The thread pool isn't static. More threads will be spun up and pressed into work if the current threads are found to be sleeping on the job (less poetically, if they're sleeping without doing useful work). There wouldn't be much point to a thread pool and queuing items otherwise -- you could just always spin up precisely `Environment.ProcessorCount` threads yourself and be done with it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/the-managed-thread-pool?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: You should be using `StopWatch` to do benchmarking instead of `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads() shows default **workerThreads=1023**. After Set ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(4, 4), the behavior is expected.

Comment: Note that, if you had a real application, and a real need to make sure only as many items were processed as you had cores (because all your work is long-running, for example), you could use `Parallel.For[Each]` with a custom `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`. Tweaking the global thread pool settings is fine for demonstration purposes, but not generally what you want to do in a production app except to work around a sub-optimal design.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, i agree with you. ```Parallel.ForEach``` is perfered. I posted this sample code because I'm debugging some other's code, and found this wired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

More threads will be triggered because you aren’t keeping your cores busy.

**Thread.Sleep** allows the thread to yield. Since your workers are mostly sleeping and not CPU bound the scheduler is free to schedule more threads.

Comment: Does it mean that system won't trigger more threads if ThreadProc() is very busy (IO/CPU-bound computation)?

Comment: It really depends on *how* busy and the settings on the pool. The goal of the scheduler is to use the CPU as much as possible.